# Problems downloading a sound recorder to Ubuntu, download won't go past 5%

Tags: software-installation

Apologies if this is a silly question, but I have been trying to download Sound Recorder from the standard Ubuntu Software program, and when I do I keep on getting the following message, and I can't proceed:

```
Unable to install "Sound Recorder"  Errors were encountered while processing: grub-efi-amd64 grub-efi-amd64-signed linux-image-4.15.0-1087-oem linux-image-4.15.0-1050-oem
```

I've googled it and nothing comes up, can anyone help?  Any assistance is gratefully received.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Have you recently updated your system ? Try deleting those packages temporarily by running : ```sudo dpkg --remove grub-efi-amd64 grub-efi-amd64-signed linux-image-4.15.0-1087-oem linux-image-4.15.0-1050-oem ```.Those are problematic because for some reason the packages couldn't be installed.Maybe because broken packages or some other reason.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  :-)  I have tried this now, and this was the results. 
=========
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of grub-efi-amd64-signed:
 shim-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64-signed.

dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of linux-image-4.15.0-1087-oem:
 linux-image-oem depends on linux-image-4.15.0-1087-oem.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-1087-oem (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing

Comment: You seem to have dependecy problems, most likely due to an interrupted previous installation. Try running `sudo apt install -f` first to fix any dependency problem.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the reply, much appreciated. Apologies for the delay in replying.  Unfortunately I am still having the problem with this and running, "sudo apt install -f" keeps on returning the same error: 

"installed linux-image-4.15.0-1050-oem package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-1043-oem
 linux-image-4.15.0-1050-oem
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"

Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks!